# How does play.libs.Json.fromJson handled a List<T> in Java?

Tags: json, playframework-2.0

I'd like to use the Json library that comes with the play 2.1 framework.
But I'm stuck with deserializing a json object back into a java List.

With gson, you can write s.th. like

```
Type type = new TypeToken<List<XYZ>>(){}.getType();
List<XYZ> xyzList = gson.fromJson(jsonXyz, type);
```

Is there a way to do the same with play.libs.Json.fromJson ?

Any help appreciated.

Edit (17.12.2013):

I did the following to work around the problem. I guess there is a better way, but I didn't found it.

```
List<MyObject> response = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
Promise<WS.Response> result = WS.url(Configuration.getRestPrefix() + "myObjects").get();
WS.Response res = result.get();
JsonNode json = res.asJson();
if (json != null) {
  for (JsonNode jsonNode : json) {
    if (jsonNode.isArray()) {
      for (JsonNode jsonNodeInner : jsonNode) {
        MyObject mobj = Json.fromJson(jsonNodeInner, MyObject.class);
        response.add(bst);
      }
    } else {
      MyObject mobj = Json.fromJson(jsonNode, MyObject.class);
      response.add(bst);
    }
  }
}
return response;
```

Comment: I ran into a similar issue, how did you resolve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Json library for Play Java is really just a thin wrapper over the Jackson JSON library (http://jackson.codehaus.org/).  The Jackson way to deserialize a list of custom objects is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9829403/deserialize-json-to-arraylistpojo-using-jackson).

For your case, once you parse the json from the response body, you would do something like this, assuming MyObject is a plain POJO:

```
JsonNode json = res.asJson();
try{
    List<MyObject> objects = new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>(){});
}catch(Exception e){
    //handle exception
}
```

I'm assuming you were asking about Play Java based on your edit, Play Scala's JSON library is also based on Jackson but has more features and syntactic sugar to accommodate functional programming patterns.

Comment: It seems with Play2 / Jackson2, this would be Json.mapper().readValue(json.traverse(), new TypeReference...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
List<YourClass> returnedRoles = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString
   ,TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructCollectionType(List.class,
   YourClass.class));
```

Comment: but this solution uses stand alone jackson mapper, and does not use play framework JSON helper and object mapper. while it may changed in Global