# How to use Jackson to deserialize a JSON document with dynamic keys?

Tags: json, jackson

I have such a JSON formatted string and the key is a random number.

```
{
  "tasks": {
    "0": {
     "key1": "value1"
    },
    "100": {
      "key1": "value2"
    }
}
```

How can I convert it to Java object by using *Jackson*?

How to define the Java class so that I can use *Jackson* like this?

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.readValue(myStr, XXXX);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jackson deserialization json to java-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14890129/jackson-deserialization-json-to-java-objects)

Comment: Thanks. Kind of different with the provided link. It's not a List in my JSON string.

Comment: have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26586103/how-to-parse-json-with-dynamic-keyname?

Comment: Please let me know if my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387683/1426227) works for you

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of approaches you could use depending on your needs:

### Using `JsonNode`

You could parse your JSON into the Jackson tree model. That is, into [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) from the [`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/package-summary.html) package:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(json);
```

You also can use Jackson to parse a [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) into a POJO:

```java
MyBean bean = mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, MyBean.class);
```

### Using `Map<String, Object>`

Depending on your requirements, you could use a `Map<String, Object>` instead of [`JsonNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html):

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> parsed = mapper.readValue(json, 
                                 new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

To convert a map into a POJO, use:

```java
MyBean bean = mapper.convertValue(map, MyBean.class);
```