# Best way to deserialize dynamic nested json

Tags: java, json

I have a nested json which looks like

```
{
 profiles : {
      "mike": "123",
      "jack": "456"
 }
}
```

The profile json can be dynamic ie I dont know how many profiles/name will be there in it. I just get the request. It could be 2 or 3 or X.
In java I tried

Company.java

```
public class company {
   @JsonProperty("profiles")
   Profiles profile;
}
```

Profiles.java

```
public class profiles{
  JsonObject info;
}
```

This is wrong. What is the right way to get that nested json?

Comment: `Map<String, String>`

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9829502/2310289

Comment: the json sample that you give does not contain array. Can you give more sample to identify which parameter is repeated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class company {
    @JsonProperty("profiles")
    Map<String, Integer> profiles;
}
```

Comment: Or `Map<String,String>`.