# Getting the right JavaType TypeFactory

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I have to deserialize my Java Object and I can't use static reference i.e TypeReference.

Like,

[mentioned in here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11936620/jackson-deserialising-json-string-typereference-vs-typefactory-constructcoll)

So, I am left with is generating the right Javatype using type factory, but somehow I am not able to get the syntax right.

Aforementioned are my Classes and Interfaces.

```
public interface Request {}

public interface Response {}

public class MyRequest implements Request {
int id;

//Getter //Setter
}

public class MyResponse implements Response {
int id;

//Getter //Setter
}

public class UberObject<S extends Request, T extends Response> implements Serializable {
private S request;
private T response;

//Getter//Setter
}

public class UberObjectWithId<S extends Request, T extends Response> extends UberObject<S, T> {
private int id;

//Getter //Setter
}

UberObjectWithId typereferencedObject = 

objectmapperobject.readValue(serialisedUberObjectWithId,

new TypeReference<UberObjectWithId<MyRequest, MyResponse>>() {});
```

The above approach works but I can't use TypeReference because of the limitation mentioned in the above link.

I tried using the Typefactory to retrieve the JavaType but I am not able to get the syntax right.

```
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametrizedType(UberObjectWithId.class,
                UberObject.class, Request.class, Response.class);
```

but the call fails

```
objectmapperobject.readValue(serialisedUberObjectWithId, type);
```

How can I resolve my particular problem?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using the correct syntax to generate the JavaType

```
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametrizedType(UberObjectWithId.class,
                UberObject.class, MyRequest.class, MyResponse.class);
```

It requires concrete classes while deserializing.