# How do I read multiple JSON objects in Java?

Tags: java, json

So this is my sample Json Text,

```
{
  "Date": [
    1545,
    "20 January 2014"
  ],
  "docText": "ABCD",
  "docSource": "",
  "docID": 99,
  "docDate": "",
  "Date": [
    1930,
    "1995/11",
    "past decade",
    "today",
    "Today"
  ],
  "docText": "JJJJJJJ\"",
  "Organization": [
    "x",
    "y",
    "z"
  ],
  "docSource": "",
  "docID": 98,
  "docDate": "",
  "Person": "xxxxxx"
}
```

Now I need a Java code to Read from this file and Display all the `docText`, `docID` Entities. I'm able to retrieve only one Entity.

This is the part of the code im using.

```
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

try {

    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(jsonFilePath);
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(fileReader);

    String docid = (String) jsonObject.get("docText");
    System.out.println("DocText: " +docid);

    long members = (long) jsonObject.get("docID");
    System.out.println("docID: " + members);


    JSONArray names = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("Organization");

    Iterator i = names.iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()) {

        System.out.println("Organization: "+i.next());
```

I really need this working soon! Thank you

Comment: I think you misunderstand how Stackoverflow works. Please read the Help Center.

Comment: If you need it working soon, I suggest you start working on it. Then if you have a specific bug you are stuck on, come back here with your code and the stack trace for the error, and we can help.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What's the problem?

Comment: @forgivenson I did update my part of the code. My part of the code retrieves only one json object. I need an updated piece of code to retrieve multiple lines.

Comment: The problem is we are not a code writing service. Read the Help Center.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Isn't my code visible? Java program? I'm just asking what changes i need to make to my code? And yes I do know you guys are not a code writing service.

Comment: It's not about posting your code. You are asking us to fix your code, but haven't told us what is wrong with it.

Comment: And then you put pressure that you need it soon. That's not our problem. We'll help you if we think you deserve it. With the current state of your question, I don't think you do.

Comment: Yes, please expand on your issue. Why can you only read one json object from this file? Is there an error?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think I did explain pretty clearly. I said I  need the program to read both the "doctext" and "docid" entities. But I'm able to read only one entity and not the next one.   

Okay so you guys only fix code only if there's an error?

Comment: @forgivenson No there's no error. Im just wondering what more should i write in there to be able to read multiple entities or json objects? I've researched a lot but found nothing.

Comment: Is this homework? If not, you know there are JSON parsers out there, tried and tested?

Comment: @JamesB Well yeah you could say that. But yes I did use JSON parsers. But they're all for reading stuff for one JSON object. My file contains multiple nested json objects. So i dont know how to read multiple lines.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246157/how-to-parse-a-json-string-to-an-array-using-jackson

Comment: fgb makes a very good point. You are not going to be able to read this into an object, given the duplicate field names.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that. Thanks for the help though @JamesB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON file has duplicate keys so you probably can't read them all using a standard parser.

From http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt:

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly brackets surrounding zero or more name/value pairs (or members).  A name is a string.  A single colon comes after each name, separating the name from the value.  A single comma separates a value from a following name.  **The names within an object SHOULD be unique.**

Instead, I'd expect each entity to be a separate object within an array.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no option to fetch multiple values from a JSON object in a single get...