# Jackson ObjectMapper deserialize object with array

Tags: java, arrays, json, jackson, objectmapper

There are some similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349421/how-to-use-jackson-to-deserialise-an-array-of-objects) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246157/how-to-parse-a-json-string-to-an-array-using-jackson), but they don't quite match my situation. My JSON string consists of an object with an array:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Sample training",
      "date": "2016-10-03 10:00:00",
      "subscription": "2016-09-20 12:34:50"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Second training",
      "date": "2016-10-06 10:00:00",
      "subscription": "2016-09-20 12:54:50"
    }
  ]
}
```

Each object in the array is a Java bean:

```
public class TrainingInfo {

    private int id;
    private String title;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime date;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    private LocalDateTime subscription;

    // Consructors, getters and setters omitted 
    // ...
}
```

I am able to read a single `TrainingInfo` with:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
TrainingInfo training = mapper.readValue(jsonTrainingInfo, TrainingInfo.class);
```

But I am not able to read the whole array. I have tried to create a new Java bean just containng an array and read it, like so:

```
private class TrainingsArray {
    private TrainingInfo[] data;

    public TrainingInfo[] getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(TrainingInfo[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
TrainingsArray trainings = mapper.readValue(jsonTrainingsArray, TrainingsArray.class);
```

But this just throws an `IOException`. 
What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** The exception thrown:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of JsonMapperTest$TrainingsArray: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
 at [Source: {
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Sample training",
      "date": "2016-10-03 10:00:00",
      "subscription": "2016-09-20 12:34:50"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Second training",
      "date": "2016-10-06 10:00:00",
      "subscription": "2016-09-20 12:54:50"
    }
  ]
}; line: 2, column: 3]

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:1456)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1012)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1205)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:148)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3798)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2842)
    at JsonMapperTest.shouldMapJsonResponseToTrainingsArray(JsonMapperTest.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Comment: Could you please include the `IOException`?

Comment: I think because you've defined it as a private class.

Comment: Make your TrainingsArray class a top-level class, or at least a static nested class instead of an inner class. An inner class needs a reference to its outer instance to be constructed. Jackson would have to create an instance of JsonMapperTest. And it won't do that.

Comment: make your class `TrainingsArray` accessible by making it `public` instead of `private`, if you want to keep it as an inner class make it `static` too

Comment: JB and Nicolas are correct, inner class may be a problem as well, I assumed it was a normal class...

Comment: @grape_mao @Nicolas Filotto @JB Nizet you were all right. It was enough to change the class from `private` to `public` to make the test work. I just didn't think that would affect... If any of you makes an actual answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Nowadays some people write long answers to simple questions just to earn more points, which is meaningless and a waste of time for me.

Comment: I agree, but I believe it is still nice to have an answer, even if it's a short one like "Make your class public instead of private". For future readers, it shows straight away that a solution was found, however trivial it might have been :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However silly this might be, the solution was to make the class `TrainingsArray` public.