# Convert json String to List<List<String> with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json String that's a list of a list of strings, and need to convert it to objects of class `List<List<String>>`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246157/how-to-parse-a-json-string-to-an-array-using-jackson) it says how to convert from string to a list, but it doesn't work for me as I cannot specify the `List<List<String>>` class in `constructCollectionType`

This is my attempt, that doesn't work:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeFactory typeFactory = objectMapper.getTypeFactory();
List<List<String>> list = objectMapper.readValue(response,
   typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List.class, List.class));
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Which version of `Jackson` do you use? I tested it for the newest and it works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`TypeReference<T>`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html):

```
TypeReference<List<List<String>>> typeReference = 
        new TypeReference<List<List<String>>>() {};
List<List<String>> list = mapper.readValue(json, typeReference);
```